# How do I send special characters via SendKeys?

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to fill out a form in Selenium2.

One input has an autocomplete that I want to close, preferably by sending <kbd>esc</kbd> after the search term.
I.e. something like `driver.FindElement(By.Id("InputWithAutocomplete")).SendKeys("SearchTerm/ESC");`

Keys that I would also like to send include <kbd>del</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>a</kbd>.

**Is there a list of special characters that I can use?**

I'm using Selenium for .NET 2.8 with the FirefoxDriver.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
WebElement list1;    
list1=firefoxDriver.findElement(By.name("lst")); 
list1.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL);
```