# How to use Selenium to enter a tab character into a textarea?

Tags: java, html, selenium

I'm using Selenium Web Driver (Java, Chrome Browser). I would like to enter a tab character into a text area. By default, entering a tab character causes the next input to be focused, but I actually want the tab character to be printed into the *textarea* input.

Since my tests are running on a windows machine, I thought I could use the alt-code to enter the tab. IE

1. Hold alt
2. Press 0
3. Press 9
4. Release alt

But I'm not sure how to do this programmatically with *WebDriver*. I tried the following:

```
WebElement myTextArea = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("form textarea"));

myTextArea.sendKeys("before_tab", Keys.chord(Keys.ALT, Keys.NUMPAD0, Keys.NUMPAD9), "after_tab");
```

...but it just printed "before_tabafter_tab" into the text area, I guess because it's pressing ALT, 0, and 9 all at the same time which doesn't translate to a printable character.

I would also consider pasting either via keyboard shortcut or context menu (this is actually closer to how I expect the user to enter text into the *textarea*), but I can't see how to put the text onto the clipboard for the selenium-driven browser to access.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7875416/how-do-i-send-special-characters-via-sendkeys

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503736/key-press-in-ctrla-selenium-webdriver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following piece of *Java* code:

```
Robot rb = new Robot();

StringSelection textToPaste= new StringSelection("  ");//make sure u enter tab here

Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(textToPaste, null);

rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);    
rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);    
rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);    
rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't use the robot class, but your answer tells me how to put text onto the clipboard and that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using **robot** class

**Focus on the text area**

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("form textarea")).sendKeys("");
```

**Use robot class to enter keys into text area**

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_0);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_9);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_0);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_9);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
```

Hope this helps you...

Answer (score -1):

You can use the windows Clipboard as follows:

```
 string text = "my text and tab" + Keys.Tab;
 Clipboard.SetText(text);
```

You can then use `Keys.Control + "V"` to paste this in your control.

Comment: This would convert the Enum to a string, resulting in "my text and tabTab"